# How to add a custom convert to ruby csv?

Tags: ruby, csv

Consider a CSV file like below. I would like to change the Credit/Debit field to 0 if they are empty strings and then do some processing.

The roundabout way that I came up with seems inefficient since I read in the csv file, apply the converter and then convert it to CSV::Table for processing. Is there a way to directly apply the converter to parse method ?

For example:

```
csv_data = <<_
Description,Debit,Credit
Eating Out,10,""
_
csv = CSV.new(csv_data, headers: true, converters: :integer)
csv.convert do |field, info|
    if info.index == 1
        field == "" ? 0 : field
    end
    if info.index == 2
        field == "" ? 0 : field
    end
end

table = CSV::Table.new(csv.to_a)  #Seems wrong to convert to array
puts table[0]['Debit']   #10
puts table[0]['Credit']  #0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the same options to [`parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse) that you can pass to `new`, and with [`new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) you can pass in an array of converters, which can be the name of one of the built-in converters, or a lambda:

```
table = CSV.parse(csv_data, headers: true, converters: [
  :integer,
  -> field, info { 'Credit' == info.header && field.empty? ? 0 : field },
  -> field, info { 'Debit' == info.header && field.empty? ? 0 : field },
])

p table # => #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:2>
puts table[0]['Debit'] # => 10
puts table[0]['Credit'] # => 0
```